# how to read properties file using spring and exposed to class

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am using spring  3.0.5 and trying to read properties files to make some kind of validation as well as datasource. But i am getting null when i use @Value ,below are my cfg.

**in applicationContext.xml**

```
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties"/>

  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

</bean>// here It is perfectly establishing the data-source.
```

**The Class where I want to exposed the values of properties file**

```
@Component
public class PropertyReaderBean {

//@Value("#{propertyConfigurer1[dailyLimit]}") 
    //@Value("#{database['jdbc.driverClassName']}")
@Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")// I tried all three but still getting null
private String limit;
public String getLimit() 
{
    System.out.println(" limit : "+limit);
    return limit;
}

public void setLimit(String limit) {
    System.out.println(" limit : "+this.limit);
    this.limit = limit;
}
```

**and finally the databse.properties file**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imps
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```

So whenever i am trying to access the values properties file using above configuration, i am getting null, please guide.

**Update:**
However the setter method of PropertyReaderBean  is not working, i have checked the stacktrace, but when i add in xml like this then i can read the properties file values.

```
<bean id="propertyDao" class="com.alw.imps.validator.PropertyReaderBean">
          <property name="limit" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely cause is **@Value** doesn't work. Did you already declare **< context:annotation-config />** in the application context?

Comment: no , should i need  < context:annotation-config /> to be declared, ,i am using xml declaration.

Comment: if i am using xml based declared, then both annotation as well as xml based declared will work.

Comment: I forgot that you might declare < context:component-scan />, so there would be no need for < context: annotation-config />.

Could you do me another favor to make sure PropertyReaderBean and the properties placeholder in a same application context, not in parent context?

Comment: i would love to ,but i did'nt get what are trying to say. "same application context, not in parent context?" i did not get this line.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk The most easiest wait to check those beans in a same application context is to look into the applicationContext.xml file. If two lines of code below are in this file, it means the beans in one context. 

`<context:component-scan base-package=".. the package of PropertyReaderBean  .."/>`



`<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need property configurer, the definition of which in your code has syntax errors.

You can just do this and reference in code as you have :

```
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>
```

which relies on this

```
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

and

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
```

Comment: did what you said but Still getting null

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk what do you log files show ? Are you sure the properties file is on classapth ?

Comment: yes, because when i set the values in applicationContext.xml file ,I can get all the properties file values inside the bean, but when i tried using annotation its resulted in null

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk how are you instantiating bean ? It must be spring managed.